# Unable To Match Legacy Serialized XML When Using ServiceStack.Text

Tags: c#-4.0, servicestack-text

Here is the legacy Message class that has all of the XML attributes with the output that is generated using the built-in .NET serializer:

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestTcpServer/Schemas/Schema.xsd", ElementName = "message", IsNullable = true)]
    public class MessageModel
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "type")]
        public string ShipmentType { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "version")]
        public int? Version { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "message-id")]
        public string MessageID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "payload")]
        public string Payload { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ip-address")]
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

which produces the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<q1:message xmlns:q1="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestTcpServer/Schemas/Schema.xsd">
  <q1:type>Test</q1:type>
  <q1:version d2p1:nil="true" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
  <q1:id>9976</q1:id>
  <q1:message-id>1</q1:message-id>
  <q1:date>2/22/2017 4:50:01 PM</q1:date>
  <q1:payload>Test Payload</q1:payload>
  <q1:ip-address>192.168.1.1</q1:ip-address>
</q1:message>
```

The new DTO that was created to be used with ServiceStack looks like this:

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestTcpServer/Schemas/Schema.xsd", Name = "message")]
    public class TIBCOMessage
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "type")]
        public string ShipmentType { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "version")]
        public int? Version { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "message-id")]
        public string MessageId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "payload")]
        public string Payload { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ip-address")]
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

which generates the following XML when performing a .ToXml() using ServiceStack.Text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestTcpServer/Schemas/Schema.xsd">
    <date>2/22/2017 4:50:01 PM</date>
    <id>9976</id>
    <ip-address>192.168.1.1</ip-address>
    <message-id>1</message-id>
    <payload>Test Payload</payload>
    <type>Test</type>
    <version i:nil="true" />
</message>
```

Firstly, there is the extra namespace being added that I can manually remove.  However, I have no idea where the "q1:"s that are prepended to each element of the original are coming from.

Is there any configuration that I can change to get ServiceStack to produce the exact same XML message?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack uses .NET Framework's built-in XML [DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) where the limited customization that's available is via the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` Attributes and the [Assembly ContractNamespaceAttribute](http://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support#changing-the-default-namespace) where you can set a global namespace for different C# namespaces.

Having said that the 2 XML documents are semantically the same. The `q1` is an autogenerated namespace alias which indicates that each Element or Attribute prefixed with `q1:` is from the referenced `Schema.xsd`:

```
<q1:message xmlns:q1="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestTcpServer/Schemas/Schema.xsd">
```

Whereas the DataContract XML says it's using a default XML namespace so each Element or Attribute without a namespace prefix is from the referenced `Schema.xsd`:

```
<message xmlns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/TestTcpServer/Schemas/Schema.xsd">
```

So they should be semantically equivalent, but if your client is expecting the exact same XML then I'd use the exact same model and serializer and just return the generated xml, e.g:

```
[AddHeader(ContentType = "text/xml")]
public object Any(MyRequest request)
{
    var response = ...;
    var xml = XmlSerializer.SerializeToString(response);
    return xml;
}
```